# Can I use Symfony's validation constraint NotEqualTo case insensitive

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony4

I am trying to use Symfony's Validation Constraint `NotEqualTo` to prevent usage of a certain string value.

As the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotEqualTo.html) states this should be possible using the NotEqualTo constraint.
This works, albeit in a case sensitive manner. However I would need this to also work in a case insensitive manner.
I could solve this by creating a custom constraint, but maybe I'm just overlooking a more trival solution.

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=4,
     *     max=150
     * )
     * @Assert\NotEqualTo(
     *     value="bar"
     * )
     */
    private $name;
}
```

In this example the reserved keyword is `bar`.
Symfony will not allow `bar` but will allow `Bar`, `BAR`, `BaR`, ...

Can I use Symfony's validation constraint `NotEqualTo` in a case insensitive manner?

Comment: NotEqualTo is case insensitive. NotEqualTo is a != comparision. Aka if I did "cat" != "CaT" it would return false because they are equal. The one that is case sensitive is NotIdenticalTo. "This constraint compares using !=, so 3 and "3" are considered equal. Use NotIdenticalTo to compare with !==."

Comment: I just went ahead and verified this on my Symfony install, it's infact not case sensitive.

Comment: @TimHinz I assume, OP wants bar, Bar, BAR etc. to be seen as equal. it is compared with != so those are definitely seen as not equal.

Comment: @TimHinz thank's for you answer. But it is indeed my intention to allow all possible case variations as Jakumi hinted at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `NotEqualTo`, as confirmed before.

An easy way to solve the problem is by using [`Regex`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html) from the String Constraints

```
 /**
  * @Assert\Regex(
  *     pattern="/^(bar)$/i",
  *     match=false,
  *     message="'Bar' is a reserved name",
  * )
  */
 private $name;
```

It is also possible to create your own custom constraint. But I feel not writing code safer.

Comment: Hey Thomas, tbh, that's even a better solution! (because it's easier and everything's build already). I wouldn't mind, if you'd mark your own answer as the solution ;o)

Answer (score 1):

`NotEqualTo` compares its values via `!=`. Since `'bar' != 'BAR'` you can't turn it around.

However, you probably could either easily add validation with a callback function to compare the lowercase versions of both values. Or your could write your own Constraint & Validator: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

You probably want to extend [Symfony/Component/Validator/AbstractComparison](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Constraints/AbstractComparison.php) (already provides the "value" attribute/property) and the respective Validator.

In the spirit of full disclosure: OP has found a better way to solve their problem: Using the built-in Regex constraint (see answer below).

Comment: I found a non-coding solution to the problem, I added it as an answer, thank you for confirming my suspicions about `NotEqualTo`